# Taking Log to find MAXIMIZE summation of variables

Tags: optimization, logarithms

I have been reading IEEE papers on communication and in several papers the authors formed objective function like:

$\text{Maximize }    \sum_k \log r_k $

to maximize the total rate of the system of $k$ users. Here $r_k$ is the rate of the $k$'th user. Now I cant understand how taking logarithm is relevant with maximizing. This is a common case in 'Entropy Maximization'. Is there any general mathematical explanation of this? Any explanation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximizing a sum of logs over a convex set is called achieving *proportional fairness*. This is a standard goal in communication networks.  Here, $r_k$ is the communication rate achieved by user $k$.  Each user wants to maximize its own rate.  However, there are shared resources.  Let $\Lambda$ be the (typically convex) set of all possible rate vectors $(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_K)$ that the system can support.  We want to find a Pareto optimal point.  Maximizing a sum of increasing and concave utility functions is used because concave functions have a *diminishing returns* property, which says that we would prefer to make allocations relatively even (pushing up those who have lower rate).

The log function is analyzed in particular in:

Frank Kelly, "Charging and Rate Control for Elastic Traffic," European Transactions on Telecommunications, vol. 8, no. 1 pp. 33-37, Jan.-Feb. 1997.

If $\Lambda$ is a convex set, it can be shown that finding a vector $r^*=(r_1^*, \ldots, r_K^*)$ that maximizes $\sum_{k=1}^K \log(r_k)$ subject to $(r_1, \ldots, r_K) \in \Lambda$ means that: 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^K\frac{r_k-r_k^*}{r_k^*} \leq 0 $$
for all vectors $(r_1, \ldots, r_K) \in \Lambda$.  This can be interpreted as the "proportionally fair" criterion:  Consider changing from the $r^*$ vector to some other vector $r \in \Lambda$. You might be able to increase rates of particular users by deviating from  $r^*$, but the overall proportional change is never positive, where this change weights users with currently low rates $r_k^*$ more heavily, which is a fairness feature.

---

Example 1: A simple example is when the set $\Lambda$ is the set of all nonnegative rates that sum to less than or equal to 1.  Then one solution to maximizing the *linear* function $\sum_k {r_k}$ over $r \in \Lambda$ is $(1, 0, 0, ..., 0)$, which is clearly unfair since it gives one user everything.  Howevever, maximizing the strictly concave function $\sum_k \log(r_k)$ over the same set $\Lambda$ gives the (much more fair) solution $r^*=(1/K, 1/K, ..., 1/K)$.

Example 2:  Suppose $\Lambda$ is the set of all $(r_1, ..., r_K) \geq 0$ such that $r_1/2 + \sum_{k=2}^K r_k \leq 1$.  Maximizing the linear utility function $\sum_k r_k$ over $\Lambda$ gives the (unfair, and unique)  solution $(2, 0, 0, ..., 0)$.  Yet, maximizing the $\sum_k \log(r_k)$ over the same set gives the (more fair, in fact, "proportionally fair") solution: $(\frac{2}{K},  \frac{1-1/K}{K-1}, ..., \frac{1-1/K}{K-1})$.

Comment: Excellent explanation sir! I have already read the paper that u mentioned but could not understand the whole of it. but your examples makes it easier for anyone. thanks a lot. @Michael.

Comment: After seeing the constraint in example 2, one thing came to my mind. If a system starts with distribution equation rates: $r* = (1/k, \cdots, 1/k)$. The system uses a weight $w_k$ for each user, where $w_k = r_k/ \sum_k r_k$, and then say after every slot the system wants to maximize the rate of those user whose weight is higher. How can the constraint should be set to allow this? Or changing the objective function as $Maximize  \sum_k w_k \log r_k$ is sufficient to achieve that? Please answer. thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  What is the $r_k$ value in your $w_k$ weight?  If you have weights $w=(w_1, ..., w_K)$ then maximizing $\sum_k w_k \log(r_k)$ gives a vector $r^*(w)$ (which depends on $w$).

Comment: You could define a recursion that starts with a weight vector $w[1]=(w_1[1], ..., w_K[1])$, solves for $r^*(w[1])$ as the maximizer of $\sum_{k=1}^K w_k[1]\log(r_k)$, then iteratively defines $w[n+1]$ such that $w_k[n+1] = \frac{r_k^*(w[n])}{\sum_{i=1}^K r^*_i(w[n])}$. I don't know why you would want to do that, at every step it seems to give more weight to users that already have high rate (which seems the opposite of fair).  But in example 1, if we start with uniform weights, we always stay at uniform weights.  In example 2, I think we converge to the (unfair) vector $(2,0,0,...,0)$.